# Recyclerview set list size

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using firebase recyclerview to populate my data and retrieving those data from firebase realtime database. I don't want to retrieve all of my data but with a condition that is if "Available == yes " then show me the data in recyclerview. My condition is working but the problem is I have 4 data set on firebase realtime database. From them in 3 set value of available is yes .So, I supposed to get 3 list of data but I am getting all 4 set. 3 set data has actual value and 1 set taking the dummy one. How can I stop that?

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BloodModelSchema, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
    new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BloodModelSchema, UserViewHolder>(
            BloodModelSchema.class,
            R.layout.search_card,
            UserViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserViewHolder viewHolder, BloodModelSchema model, int position) {
            if(model.getAvailable().equals("Yes"))
            {
                viewHolder.setDetails(model.getBlood_Group(),model.getName(),
                        model.getArea(),model.getMobile(),
                        model.getEmail());


            }

        }


    };
recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: why don't you use a normal recyclerview adapter ? I wouldn't use the firebase one...

Comment: @OWADVL you forgot to add swift in the list of programming langauges that you know

Comment: You should be able to do this by passing a `Query` into the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` where you currently pass `databaseReference`. Can you update your question to include a snippet of the JSON at `databaseReference`? Please add it as text, no screenshots. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

If you have one databaseReference just add .limitToFirst(3)

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BloodModelSchema, UserViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BloodModelSchema, UserViewHolder>(
                    BloodModelSchema.class,
                    R.layout.search_card,
                    UserViewHolder.class,
                    databaseReference.limitToFirst(3))

            ) { .....
```

But you can create second databaseReference2 and limit it to 4. 
For different cases use two different adapters with different limitations. Good luck!

Comment: I don't know how many data set has Available == yes. So,how to do it dynamically

Comment: As i understand you have a child “Available” with value “yes” or “no”. Better use ValueEventListener for child “Available” with condition if value.equalTo(“yes”) do this, else {do this}

Comment: ValueEventListener inside populate view?

Comment: Or .orderByValue()

Comment: databaseReference.addValueEventListener ... in the beginning. Can’t find a time for searching a code. I’ll do it later.